# bootstrap btn-group not uniform height

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap btn-default, which the last one must contain a dropdown, how can I make all of them the same size?

The last one contains only a DIV shouldn't become so big

```css
.btn {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div id="header-content" style="width:100%" class="btn-group  btn-group-toggle ">

  <a href="Home.aspx" class="btn btn-default redBack a">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i><br /> Home
  </a>
  <a href="Categorie.aspx" class="btn btn-default redBack a">
    <i class="fa fa-book-open"></i><br /> Menù
  </a>
  <a href="Carrello.aspx" class="btn btn-default redBack a">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><br /> Carrello
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNumCarrello"></asp:Label>
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown btn btn-default redBack ">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle btn lblBiancoMenu a redBack" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      <i class="far fa-address-card"></i>
      <br />Profilo
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu a redBack" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a href="registrazione.aspx?Menu=1" class="redBack ">Profilo </a></li>
      <li><a href="Login.aspx" class="redBack ">Login </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have your anchor tag inside a division, you’re getting the division’s padding and the anchor’s border adding to the height. If you style the div to have no padding and the anchor to have no border (and fill the full width), you should get what you want.

```css
.btn {
     width:25%;
}
.menu-div {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.menu-dropdown {
    border: 0 !important;
    width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
   

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
<div  id="header-content" style="width:100%"  class="btn-group  btn-group-toggle " >

                  <a  href="Home.aspx"  class="btn btn-default redBack a">
                      <i class="fas fa-home"></i><br />
                    Home
                 </a>
                 <a  href="Categorie.aspx"  class="btn btn-default redBack a">
                     <i class="fa fa-book-open"></i><br />
                    Menù
                  </a>
                 <a  href="Carrello.aspx"  class="btn btn-default redBack a">
                     <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><br />
                Carrello <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNumCarrello" ></asp:Label>
                  </a>


            <div class="dropdown btn btn-default redBack menu-div"  >
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle btn lblBiancoMenu a redBack menu-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >                    
                        <i class="far fa-address-card"></i>
                       <br />Profilo
                  </a>
                                
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu a redBack" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                      <li><a  href="registrazione.aspx?Menu=1"  class="redBack ">Profilo </a></li>
                      <li><a  href="Login.aspx"  class="redBack ">Login </a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>



                </div>
```

I added a couple of new styles to show the results. You can apply the style in whatever way works with your setup, although you may have to use !important on the styles to prevent Bootstrap's btn style overriding your styles.